# Passing Doc attribute as a parameter into function on Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have the following function defined with a mongodb js script file:

```
function populateNewCollection(db, col_new, col_old, daysBack, dateAttribute) { 
    db[col_old].find(     
        { dateAttribute : {$gte: new Date("09/01/2014")}}   
        ).sort({_id: -1}).forEach(     
        function(row) { db[col_new].insert(row); }   ); }
```

I am calling the function like so:

```
populateNewCollection(db.getSiblingDB('tracking'),'TRACKING_DATA','TRACKING_DATA.old',1, 'datecreated' )
```

For some reason this silently fails however if I hardcode the `dateAttribute` param it works as so:

```
    function populateNewCollection(db, col_new, col_old, daysBack, dateAttribute) { 
        db[col_old].find(     
            { 'datecreated' : {$gte: new Date("09/01/2014")}}   
            ).sort({_id: -1}).forEach(     
            function(row) { db[col_new].insert(row); }   ); }
```

I not sure what I need to do here I am mainly a java developer, so I thought passing the in the string would work. Do I need to do some post processing within the method to inter that this is a mongo doc attribute?

EDIT:

I've even tried declaring it as a var within the function and it still fails to work:

```
 function populateNewCollection(db, col_new, col_old, daysBack, dateAttribute) { 
var date = new Date(); 
date.setDate(date.getDate() - daysBack); 
var dateAt = dateAttribute;
var  d = 'datecreated'; 
db[col_old].find(     
    { d : {$gte: new Date("09/01/2014")}}   
    ).sort({_id: -1}).forEach(     
    function(row) { db[col_new].insert(row); }   ); }
```

Comment: you may create a query object in this situation, you may give dynamic keys to that query object and you can pass this query object into find function like a parameter, then it should work.

Comment: Can you point me at an example I am working off mongo docs atm

Comment: `var query= {};` and `query["datecreated"] = {"$gte":new Date("09/01/2014")}` in find method you can pass query obj but didn't tried. If it works let me know.

Comment: It worked Thank you good sir if you want to post as a question I'll accept the answer

Comment: thanks for your feedback , i added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query= {};
```

and

```
query["datecreated"] = {"$gte":new Date("09/01/2014")}
```

and in find method you can pass query object.